# Failed to delete, alter, change...column name 'number of shares' with spaces

Tags: java, mysql

I imported a database from access to mysql but one of the table has a column name 'number of shares' with spaces but i have tried to change, replace and even drop the column name and failed. can any one be of help of how to go about it

```
String UpdateQuary = "UPDATE master SET trn_date=?,account_master=?,"
        + "title=?,first_name=?,sir_name=?,sex=?,birth_date=?,marital_status=?,"
        + "highest_educ_level=?,home_parish=?,centre=?,hiika=?,mobile1=?,"
        + "mobile2=?,email=?,kampala_residence=?,occupation=?,employer=?,"
        + "category_of_membership=?,"
        + "value_of_shares =?,number of shares=?";
```

Comment: Are you using the proper escape character, which is a backtick?

Comment: am just using the normal alter statement, kindly elaborate what you mean by backtick with a statment

Comment: where's your code or SQL?

Comment: this is the statement am using to remove spaces:mysql> UPDATE master SET number of shares=REPLACE(number of share, ' ', '');

Comment: this is the error that i get:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of sh
ares=REPLACE(number of share, ' ', '')' at line 1

Comment: You should put all important informations in question itself instead of comments, especially since comments won't let you format code/error message properly. Also people willing to help you shouldn't be made to read also comments, all relevant informations should be in question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the column with backticks:

```
update master set `number of shares` = 100 where user_id = 3;
```

For example. I'd recommend just renaming the column if you can get away with that in your project.

**Edit** To rename, try this:

```
alter table master change `number of shares` number_of_shares int(11);
```

Comment: i would actually get away with the renaming but can you help me with the correct statement for renaming. sorry for being too demanding but i seem to have tried all the options including renaming but i get are errors

Comment: Sure, do you know the definition of that column? Meaning, is it something like a varchar(255) or a number? We need to know the definition of the column to rename it under mysql.

Comment: this is it's definition:| number of shares         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |

Comment: Thanks, i think am just tired